# AntiForgeryToken And MachineKey configuration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken, machinekey

I am trying to deploy a .NET MVC application to GoDaddy servers. I have an Html.AntiForgeryToken on one of my pages that is causing it throw an exception every time I hit it.

```
Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.
```

I have generated a machine key using the following URL

```
 http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey
```

and have set the pages viewStateEncryptionMode to "Always"

```
<pages viewStateEncryptionMode="Always">
```

I am still receiving the error however and am at a lost as to what to do next. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I did a little bit more google searching and found that if I don't clear the cache on the browser it will retain the invalid viewstate. Apparently chrome holds onto some semblance of the viewstate in each consecutive browser unless all of the chrome browser windows are closed down (I use alot of chrome browsers), even when the cache has been cleared.

I found that the code worked by trying it in Firefox and IE which was successful. I then closed down all of the chrome windows (after clearing cache) and restarted. I was then able to navigate successfully to the page with the AntiForgeryToken on it.